# Page reloading on child routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Using [Angular 2 Router](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). I have a 2 level routing (`root routing` and `child routing`]

My problem is that when navigating to a child *route* the page is reloading after the Child is being loaded.

**child level routing**

```
const childRoutes: Routes = [
   {
    path: '',
    component: BaseComponent,
    children: [
           {
            path: '',
            component: DetailsComponent
           },
           {
               path: 'other',
               component: OtherComponent
           }
       ]
   }
];

export const childRouting = RouterModule.forChild(childRoutes);
```

**Top Level Routing**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/overview',
        pathMatch: 'full'},
    {
        path: 'overview',
        component: OverviewComponent},
    {
        path: 'sub',
        //This is the module which the childRoutes belongs to.
        loadChildren: 'app/components/sub.module#SubModule'
    }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

**call for navigation from DetailsComponent**

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    onSubmit() {
        this.router.navigate(['/sub/other'])
    }
}
```

**p.s**

I'm trying to keep this question short so if more code needed then please let me know and i will gladly add it.

Comment: What do you mean by "the page is reloading". I have never seen the router reloading the page. It only adds/removes components and updates the URL in the browsers URL bar.

Comment: That is why i'm really confused. full page reloading. full xhr call, getting all js files, photos and everything. page is blank..there is the ...loading indicator of angular js and then the child view re-appear. I was able to navigate to the page i wanted but then there is another http call to the same page. I will try maybe to record the screen and attach it as a gif

Comment: What's the URL of the link that should point to the child route? (what does chrome show in the toolbar when you move the mouse over the link)

Comment: Navigated to http://localhost:3000/sub/other?

Comment: Perhaps your server doesn't support HTML5 pushState. Try enabling `HashLocationStrategy` and check if you still can reproduce.

Comment: I"m not sure it's related. I'm using `lite server` for development but will try

Comment: AFAIK lite server supports HTML5 pushState but I think it's still worth a try. Do you have `<base href="/">` as first child in `<head>`?

Comment: Tried it, still happens. and yes (-: i have `<base href="/">

Comment: I missed that before. I guess this is related to your form. The reload is probably the default submit behavior. Can you please post the HTML where the submit is initiated from?

Comment: raaa...Yes u are right...when added to the submit button... type="button" everything is working as expected (-:. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by the default browser submit behavior. Either call `preventDefault()`, return `false` in the event handler or add `type="button"` to prevent the submit event default behavior.

Comment: its working but i have number of `<a>` tags, on click of `<a>` method is calling after routerLink, what to do now ? , i dont want to use `(click)...` and than routing in `.ts` file

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you please create a new question and add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish?